# How to check the validity of formula in first-order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I have the following formula in FO first order predicate logic. It is given that g is a univariate and f a bivariate function symbol and I'm trying to figure out if the formula is valid or not.

$$ {\forall x \forall y ((f(x,y) = f(y,x)\wedge \sim \forall z f(f(x,y),z) = f(x,f(y,z))), \exists x \forall y \  g(y)=x} $$

I assume $ f(x,y) = f(y,x)$ means that the formula requires f to be symmetric. Also $f((f(x,y),z) = f(x,f(y,z)) $ is basically the associativity equation and the last condition $ \exists x \forall y \ g(y)=x$ means that g must be surjective, if I'm correct. 
That's how far I've gotten so far. I'm not sure what to do from here.

I'm a little confused. It there is anybody who could help, I'd be grateful. Thanks in advance

Comment: The second part is negated; thus, it means that $f$ is **not** associative.

Comment: *Validity* means "true in every interpretation"...

Comment: I don't get it. You seem to have **two** formulas, separated by a comma. Does the comma have some special meaning? And $\exists x\forall y g(y)=x$ says that $g$ is **constant**, not that it's surjective; surjectivity would be $\forall x\exists y g(y)=x$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA It seems to be saying more than that $f$ is not associative; because the quantifiers are what they are, it's saying that for every choice of $x$ and $y$ there is a $z$ for which the associativity equation fails.

Comment: Anyway, the formulas are **obviously** not logically valid. Just $f$ to be some noncommutative binary operation and $g$ some nonconstant function. What's the problem?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments!  Okay, I see now that g is supposed to be constant.  But the intriguing part was the comma between the two last formulas. I have no idea what that comma should mean.

Comment: Is it possible that the comma means "logical and"  as in the language Prolog? But then I don't understand why they wouldn't use the symbol $ \land $ instead, just as before.